# What's the below URL encode type (this type: `%23E6%2588%`)?

Tags: url, encode

What's the below URL encode type?

```
https://demo.com/base/__jdexzkod__%23E6%2588%2510%25E5%25B0%25B1%25E5%278D%25A1.jpg
```

at first I thought it's urlencoded, but not, the urlencode should be like this: `%xx%yy%zz`, but there have 4 numbers.

Comment: What makes you think the two characters following the percent-encoding need encoding themselves? Why is this not simply `#E6%88`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it can still be URL encoded.

According to https://www.urldecoder.org/

```
https://demo.com/base/__jdexzkod__%23E6%2588%2510%25E5%25B0%25B1%25E5%278D%25A1.jpg
```

decodes into

```
https://demo.com/base/__jdexzkod__#E6%88%10%E5%B0%B1%E5'8D%A1.jpg
```